# Popover on specific words in entry

Tags: plugin-development, entries

I need to create a popover on words to explain in more detail what that word actually means. It's kind of a dictionary for technical words.

But I would like to avoid to many queries and use it like Twig's translate filter. But the customer needs to add new descriptions to specific words from CP.

Could I please get some advice or pointer for further development?

Comment: What code or technique have you already tried? As it stands this question is borderline "off-topic".

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin to make it possible for you customer to add new descriptions to a translation file: https://github.com/boboldehampsink/translate.